# Can't get my gem based theme to work. Theme can't find layouts

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've tried Googling all over for solutions to this, and followed various instructions on creating my own gem based theme, and it still does not work for me. I had created a bunch of Jekyll themes before they became gem based and didn't have any issues with that.

Now when I try to run the theme, I get a bunch of errors saying:

```
 Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in _posts/2016-8-20-etiam.md does not exist.
 Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in _posts/2016-8-21-consequat.md does not exist.
 Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in _posts/2016-8-22-ipsum.md does not exist.
 Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in _posts/2016-8-23-magna.md does not exist.
 Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in _posts/2016-8-24-tempus.md does not exist.
 Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in _posts/2016-8-25-aliquam.md does not exist.
 Build Warning: Layout 'home' requested in index.md does not exist.
```

I am new to ruby gems, so I am thinking I'm doing something wrong with creating the gem. I also tested my GitLab Pages site out with the default Minima gem based theme, and it works when I switch to that or Minimal Mistakes (also gem based). However, when I try adding my own theme (forty_jekyll_theme) these errors are displayed on the build, the build succeeds, and my site's code output is just index.md. There is nothing in the `<head>` or anywere else.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file? And the repo if it's open source.

Comment: The `post` layout is being requested by the files in `_posts/`, you need a file at `_layouts/post.html`. Ditto for the `home` layout.

Comment: In case you didn't see my last comment, I deleted my answer to avoid confusion as the issue seems different to what I'd original thought. Sorry mate, but best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I forgot to specify which gem theme I was using in my `_config.yml`.

For example to use your theme `jekyll-custom-theme` you would need to add the `theme` attribute in your file:

```
... # your _config.yml configurations

theme: jekyll-custom-theme # Specify the gem theme
```

Make sure to also have the gem of the theme with the current version in your `Gemfile` like:

```rb
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'jekyll-custom-theme', '~> 0.0.1'
```